# Tunneling a local command through SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

What is the best way to run a command through an ssh tunnel? Not running the command *on* the remote server, but forwarding locally created traffic to it through a tunnel.

For example, `wget`. How can I run `wget` on my local machine so that it tunnels to a VPS that I have ssh access to? Both the local and remote servers are running Arch Linux.

Comment: what OS are you running? local and server ?

Comment: both Arch Linux, question edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh tunnel for local (not remote) command execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469501/ssh-tunnel-for-local-not-remote-command-execution)

Answer (score 1):

From what i got, your question is about a proxy, specifically, a socks proxy . So the easiest way to do this is to show you some examples. and work from that.

```
ssh -NT -D 1080 user@remoteserver.net
```

What this is doing is keeping the port `1080` open as a socks5 proxy `-NT` keeps the connection alive. 
Then what needs to be done is to use the proxy. I dont think wget has the option to use a socks proxy so we will have to use `curl` as i know that can use them.

```
curl -O  --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:1080 url
```

This connects to the socks proxy and downloads from url.